# Cannot make active Excel window when it is minimized

Tags: excel, vbscript

Part of my code is:
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate("Book1 - Excel")
Now i have opened afew applications in desktop and when Excel is behind others this part makes its window active. But if i minimize excel and run this part, it does not restore it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Already tried Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.SendKeys "% r"

Comment: Thanks both are ok for this script. I was thinking to do it more general. This works for the obj i create but is there a way to activate any window that is open? (example can be IE, winExplorer, or any other app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It works fine for me.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate("Book1 - Excel") 
WScript.Sleep 500   'sleep is required here to make this work
objShell.SendKeys "% x" ' to maximize
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop that approach altogether. `SendKeys` is a very, *very* poor way of automating things and should not be used at all. If you need to automate MS Office applications use the respective COM object:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add

...

wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Comment: **bold** TNX this is OK